# How to scrape all the prices using Selenium and Python

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get ticket prices from Viagogo with not luck. The scrip seems quite simple, and works with other websites but not for Viagogo. I have no issue in getting the text in the title from here.

It always return me an empty result( i.e. `[]`). Can anyone help?

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

s = Service("[]/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get('https://www.viagogo.com/Concert-Tickets/Country-and-Folk/Taylor-Swift-Tickets/E-151214704')
price = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value('//div[@id="clientgridtable"]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/span[@class="t-b fs16"]'))
Print(price)
[]
```

I'am expecting the 7 prices defined in the right hand side of the website situated just above "per ticket"

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the definition of `price`, it should be `value='...'` instead of `value('...')`. Moreover, you should define it using a wait command so that the driver waits for the prices to be visible on the page.

```
price = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "...")))
```

Notice that this command needs the following imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: It partially worked, but only if I click in the website while python is running, selecting: 1) the number of tickets I want, 2) if I want to have the 2 seats next to each other, and 3) clicking continue.
Any lead on how I can do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

To extract all the 7 prices defined in the right hand side within the [website](https://www.viagogo.com/Concert-Tickets/Country-and-Folk/Taylor-Swift-Tickets/E-151214704?qty=1) you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.f-list__cell-pricing-ticketstyle > div.w100 > span")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`get_attribute("innerHTML")`*:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='f-list__cell-pricing-ticketstyle']/div[@class='w100 ']/span")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Rs.25,509', 'Rs.25,873', 'Rs.27,403', 'Rs.28,788', 'Rs.72,809', 'Rs.65,593', 'Rs.29,153', 'Rs.29,153']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```